# How to move current date to the first row of the jQuery datepicker calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

Is that possible to shift current day to the first row of the datepicker calendar? So the first row always contains the current day.

[image]

Comment: Not possible with this date picker

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any other plugin available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will set minDate as First date of current month and maxdate as last date of current month.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
    // First Date Of the month 
    var startDateFrom = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(),currentTime.getMonth(),1);
    // Last Date Of the Month 
    var startDateTo = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(),currentTime.getMonth() +1,0);

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        minDate: startDateFrom,
        maxDate: startDateTo
    });
```